# How can I write a "relation" symbol as a raised small R?

Tags: math-mode, macros

[image]
I need to write A R B in Latex. I know that there is \rho option, but I need exactly what you see in the picture.

Comment: how about A \textsuperscript{R} B  or A \raisebox{3pt}{R} B ?

Answer (score 3):

Make a single superscript into a relation symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Srel}[1]{\mathrel{{}^{#1}\kern-\scriptspace}}

\begin{document}

$A\Srel{R}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only trick is to remove the `\scriptspace` that's added to an atom having a subscript or superscript.